# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Unable to find a usable idle daemon

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

My laptop ram is 8gb
I'm stuck here for few days i could't solve this problem
I want to run flutter and android emulator properly on android studio
i changed gradle.properties to org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx128M but facing problems
please help
thank you for helping

.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to find a usable idle daemon. I have connected to 100 different daemons but I could not use any of them to run the build. BuildActionParameters were DefaultBuildActionParameters{, currentDir=C:\src\testapp\android, systemProperties size=56, envVariables size=61, logLevel=QUIET, useDaemon=true, continuous=false, injectedPluginClasspath=[]}